# Gmail Email Markup -- Event Showing UTC Time Instead of Local

Tags: google-schemas

Our Gmail Email Markup was working fine for more than a year. Now it shows the incorrect time in the bubble above an email. It still adds the event to the calendar with the correct time.

The event time: June 22, 2020, 17:00 (15:00 UTC). Computer local time is UTC+2.

**The Email Markup**

[image]

**The Email Bubble as Rendered in Gmail** (Notice the time is shown as the UTC time, not local time.)
[image]

**The Calendar Event Added** (Note this time is correct).

[image]

I think it is pretty clear there has been a bug introduced that causes the dates to no longer display correctly in emails. However, no one else seems to be saying anything about this, so it makes me wonder if somehow I am implementing this incorrectly. Does anyone have insight into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Writing this question got me thinking. I realized that email bubble within Gmail just displays whatever the `startDate` time is without converting it to the local time of the user. So while I was using:

```
"startDate": "2020-06-22T15:00:00Z"
```

what I wanted was the same time, but in local time.

```
"startDate": "2020-06-22T10:00:00-05:00"
```

Both of these add the event to the correct time in the user's calendar. However, they will display differently within Gmail itself. It's possible that this adjustment by Google is actually a bug-fix that also broke my code.